# Open phantomJS using robot framework with javascript off

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, robotframework

Is there a way to open PhantomJS browser with JavaScript off?

I have used the following code but JavaScript is still enabled.

```
Open Browser   url  phantomjs  desired_capabilities=javascriptEnabled:False
```

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** The Robot framework uses Selenium to run web tests. The Selenium Webdriver support in PhantomJS is provided by Ghostdriver which is fully implemented in JavaScript and partially runs inside of the page context. If JavaScript would be disabled, then you couldn't use the webdriver protocol anymore to talk to PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks for your answser, so is it possible to open PhantomJS  and then disable Javascript on the page itself?

Comment: See the very first option [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html). You can change it during execution (if you send a special webdriver message to Ghostdriver), but you probably cannot interact with the page anymore besides taking screenshots and getting the page source. You also probably cannot exactly determine the time that you need to set this option, because there is no event to distinguish receiving the HTML and receiving all the resources and executing them immediately. If you don't need to interact with the page, then you can use some request framework.